# Text smaller on screen resize

Tags: html, css

I'm making the first project in Freecodecamp's Responsive Web Design Certification and I'm having an issue with some text size.

I have included some FontAwesome icons as pseudoelements and wrapped some dates within a span tag in order to give them some extra spacing.

The issue is that in smaller screen sizes both the dates and the icons get smaller but it doesn't happen with the rest of the text.

My code for the icons is:

```
li:before{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.bullet-1:before{
    content:"\f0f8";
}
```

And for the dates:

```
.year{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

How could I fix it? This is the Pen:

https://codepen.io/rubenvillarnet/pen/aQzBxV

Thanks a lot

Edit: thanks a lot for your answers. I'm sorry I'm didn't explain me well enough. Here is some clarification:

- The issue only happens on mobile devices or in Chromes's Device tab. It works well if the browser is simply resized.
- I have tried with *vh* units but the icons and dates still appear much smaller than the rest of the text.

Comment: When I look at your codepen and resize the screen I can't see the icons getting smaller. However, to answer your question, you can either use `media queries` give the `font-size` of your text a size define in `vw` (rather than `px`). See [here](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) for more information.

Comment: I can't recreate the problem. Nothing changes on resize. Btw, you should **always** include relevant code in your question along with the link.

Comment: I don't know the full answer to your issue, but just so you have something to begin with, the dates and icons are not getting smaller. It's the rest of the text that gets bigger. I didn't figured the cause yet, but that's where you should focus on.

Comment: @NickParsons - you need to toggle the `device toolbar` on chrome and then you'll see the issue

Comment: Is this happening on mobile or when you resize your browser's window down?

Comment: @vsync It only happens on mobile or in Chromes's Device tab.

Answer (score -1):

Better approach we can use for font size responsive structure

```
html, body { font-size: 5vw }
h1 { font-size: 2em }
h2 { font-size: 1.5em }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `font-size: 1vw`

You can read more about viewport size here: [CSS Tricks - Viewport sized](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)